# "Circular Redirect" errors in Facebook open graph debugger after API was upgraded to 2.6

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

On April 12th, Facebook upgraded the FB App we use to share new articles to our page to API version 2.6. Since then, stories get posted, but the image is usually not added to the story.

When I check with the opengraph debugger, I see strange errors like:

```
Circular Redirect
We could not resolve the canonical URL because the redirect path contained a cycle.
```

With redirect paths of:

```
Redirect Path   
Input URL   arrow-right https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/government/34-tech-firms-sign-accord-not-to-assist-government-hacking-operations/
301 HTTP Redirect   arrow-right https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/government/34-tech-firms-sign-accord-not-to-assist-government-hacking-operations/
```

Even stranger, sometimes the redirect paths show urls like below, which are not from my site:

```
Input URL   arrow-right https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/crooks-hijack-router-dns-settings-to-redirect-users-to-android-malware/
301 HTTP Redirect   arrow-right https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/crooks-hijack-router-dns-settings-to-redirect-users-to-android-malware/?utm_content=70198165&utm_medium=social&utm_source=facebook
og:url Meta Tag arrow-right https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/security/crooks-hijack-router-dns-settings-to-redirect-users-to-android-malware/
```

Once I click on the scrape button again, it gets rid of the error, but the images still do not show in the post on my FB page.

It is almost as if the scraper is targeting URLs that are not mine, even though I am sending them correctly and I have the same urls in my og:url and canonical tags.

Any ideas?

Comment: _“but the images still do not show in the post on my FB page”_ - posts you already made before you cleared the cache do not get updated automatically; you have to do that via the UI (there’s an option like “refresh share attachment” or similar in the post context menu.)

Comment: Not seeing that option. In the past if I updated the image associated with an article on my site and scraped again, FB would automatically update the image in the post as well.

Comment: That must have been a long time ago then, I guess? If that was ever the case (never experienced that myself), they still have fixed it by now. Would just be dangerous and invite all kinds of abuse otherwise (I make you share that link with the cute kitten picture today, and switch the image out for “ch34p v14gr4 h3r3!!!1” tomorrow ... pretty obvious that this must not be possible.)

Comment: Agreed. For me the articles in question are only generated by our writers, rather than user submitted content that can be changed. Still frustrating that I Facebook is picking up these strange redirects.